# iMacro Increase Position

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

I am trying to make something within iMacros for cloudflare that activate the CDN by clicking on the orange cloud. However for each field that needs turned on the position of the cloud button also increases.

```
TAG POS=42 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:cloud&&TXT:

TAG POS=43 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:cloud&&TXT:

TAG POS=44 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:cloud&&TXT:
```

Is there a way that I can increase this position each time? I.e set default position 1, then run the same command until position is `500`?

Thanks

```
TAG POS=45 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:cloud&&TXT:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:cloud&&TXT:
```

Try this.